# Linux file descriptor - getting current redirection stdout file?

Tags: linux, file, ksh, descriptor

I'm trying to get the current stdout redirection, and having some trouble.

I have a script that is always run with stdout redirection ie:

```
myscript.sh > /tmp/output.log
```

In myscript.sh, I need to find out what file it is being output to.

I'm trying this currently (not working):

```
logfile=$(readlink -f /proc/self/fd/1)
```

That's outputting logfile = /tmp/sflq.r3f, for instance.  I need to instead find that it's going to /tmp/output.log

Is this even possible?

I'm using korn shell if it matters...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$()` uses a pipe (or as it appears for ksh -- a tempfile which ksh appears to use to emulate what usually is a pipe in other shells) to capture the output of readlink.

Inside `$()`, the stdout is that pipe (or tempfile in ksh's case).

You can get around this interposed stdout file with something like:

```
{ logfile=$(readlink -f /proc/self/fd/3); }  3>&1
# my ksh 93 needs the { ;} -- dash, and zsh don't 
echo "The logfile is: $logfile"
```

Now:

```
./myscript.sh > /tmp/output.log
echo OUTPUT.LOG
cat /tmp/output.log
```

should give you:

```
OUTPUT.LOG
The logfile is: /tmp/output.log
```

---

Another option is to think of a way avoid the variable altogether:

```
echo -n "The logfile is: "
readlink -f /proc/self/fd/1 #goes straight to stdout so no need to capture
```

Comment: The logfile is: /proc/18117/fd/3

Comment: @John Sorry, should have tested it in ksh. For `ksh`, I need to add to braces like shown above. Then it works for me (` ksh version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`)

Comment: that did it!  Is there a short version of why the braces are required, or is that something I should spend some time after work looking up?  Thank you, sir!

Comment: I'd call it a ksh bug. I figured if that redirection didn't trigger after the capture assignment, I'd put a block around it and redirect at the block level, where redirections should work for sure.

Comment: Well, you've certainly given me something to look into.  I've no idea what braces in a script are used for: I need to correct that, it seems.  Thanks, again, it's working great!

Comment: @John: Enclosing multiple commands in curly braces (`{ ...; ...; }`) is a [group command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) that allows you to treat multiple commands as a single unit, such as with respect to redirections.

Comment: @PSkocik: Bash's behavior must have changed recently: in `bash` v4.3.11 I see the same behavior as in your `ksh 93u+` version (won't work without curly braces); great answer, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, you seem to be quite fixated on the `/proc/*self*/fd`. Do consider what exactly does this **self** mean in the context of your code invocation and if using something like `/proc/$$/fd` in the script's body wouldn't be a better idea…

(Hint: `$(readlink …)` is executed in a subshell.)

Comment: That's a good point and makes for a much simpler solution, though spelling that solution out would be more helpful (perhaps the lack of doing so, combined with the folksy delivery is what prompted the down-vote).

Comment: @mklement0 fortunately I'm not here for up-votes; and the answer is there anyway – `/proc/$$/fd`. Perhaps I should have spelled this out explicitly…

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, but I assume you're here to share knowledge effectively.
Yes, your answer contains all relevant information (and I up-voted it), but its _form_ gets in the way of communicating that information effectively.
Also consider that if your answer is _recognizably_ superior, it will attract up-votes, and over time the focus on contrasting it with the sub-optimal approach (`self`) will become less important.